# passing data using a generic protocol

Tags: swift

I have this generic function that push a view controller based on passed generic data

```
func processListData<T: FormDataSource>(title: String, data: [T]) {
    let vc = ListViewController(data: data)
    vc.coordinator = self
    push(vc, title: title.localized())
}
```

In the caller site, If I used this code

```
func handleTableSelection(cellData: (String, [FormDataSource])){
    let (title,dataSource) = cellData
    coordinator?.processListData(title: title, data: dataSource)
}
```

it shows the following error

> Value of protocol type 'FormDataSource' cannot conform to
> 'FormDataSource'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to
> protocols

so I had to cast FormDataSource variable in order to be able to call processListData as following

```
func handleTableSelection(cellData: (String, [FormDataSource])){
        
        let (title,dataSource) = cellData
        
        if let assumptions = dataSource as? [Assumption] {
            coordinator?.processListData(title: title, data: assumptions)
        } else if let stakeholders = dataSource as? [StakeHolder] {
            coordinator?.processListData(title: title, data: stakeholders)
        }
        //.... tons of else if
```

Is there any better way to keep it generic and pass dataSource without casting all possible model?

Comment: Did you try to limit `FormDataSource ` protocol to class only? Something like `protocol FormDataSource: class { }`.

Comment: Can you make `handleTableSelection` generic? `func handleTableSelection<U: FormDataSource>(cellData: (String, [U])) {`

Comment: @ben yes, I tried that but it shows same error

Comment: @vadian doing that will move the issue up to the caller tableView(tableView:didSelectRowAt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `processListData` has a generic variable `T`, then `handleTableSelection`  must also have the same form,
You can delete `<T: FormDataSource>` in A, like this:

```
func processListData(title: String, data: [FormDataSource]) {
    let vc = ListViewController(data: data)
    vc.coordinator = self
    push(vc, title: title.localized())
}
```

Comment: @DotFreelancer FormDataSource is a protocol not a type. If you create an array of elements that conform to a protocol you won’t be able to access the properties of the type that conforms to it that is not required by the protocol.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for mentioning that. It's fine in my case; I only use a property declared in FormDataSource protocol.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing generics you have to give compiler to infer types statically from usage.

As far as I could replicate your code here is a possible direction to solve this case without run-time casting (it will require modifications in other not provided code as well, but seems the idea should be clear)

```
enum DataSourceStorage {
    case assumption([Assumption])
    case stakeholder([StakeHolder])

    func process(with coordinator: Coordinator?, title: String) {
        switch self {
          case .assumption(let assumptions):
            coordinator?.processListData(title: title, data: assumptions)
          case .stakeholder(let stakeholders):
            coordinator?.processListData(title: title, data: stakeholders)
        }
    }
}
```

and now it can be handled directly

```
func handleTableSelection(cellData: (String, DataSourceStorage)){
    let (title,dataSource) = cellData
    dataSource.process(with: coordinator, title: title)
}
```

as it is about static typing so in corresponding places the workflows should be separated explicitly to be called like

```
handleTableSelection(cellData: (title, .assumption(data))
```